# Simulate WAN / Route Between 2 Virtual networks (Vmware)

Tags: networking, active-directory, vmware-esxi, wide-area-network

i am in the process of doing some Labs on VMWARE ESXI 5.5, i am currently testing replication between 2 AD sites,

i have set up Site A containing 2 DC's and want to setup Site B Contains 2 DC's as well, there on different Virtual networks and sub nets to simulate the sub nets & locations in real life.

Site A runs 2 DHCP 80/20 pushing out 192.168.1.0/24 - UK Virtual Network  (VSwitch)
Site B Runs 2 DHCP 80/20 Pushing out 192.168.2.0/24 - USA Virtual Network (VSwitch)

ideally if its around i am after something to allow me to route between the 2 separate virtual networks so a DC i am setting up in Site B with a statically set IP address on 192.168.2.0/24 can still contact the DC's in site A via a Default gateway / router type thing.

in real live we a have a VPN setup between the 2 sites that allows for replication traffic to flow so this wont be an issue, i just want an accurate LAB environment.

Hope i have been clear in my explanation the situation, i am happy to explain further if something is unclear.

i have good fundamental knowledge of ESXI/Vmware but i may be missing a really basic way to achieve this.

thanks for you time.

Gordon

Comment: i found a bit of software called pfSense seems to what i was after any more suggestions are welcome however.

Comment: pfSense works well, it's based on FreeBSD. DD-WRT has a x64 version that runs in ESXi as well, it's based on Linux. If you're not familiar with either base OSes there isn't *much* advantage to either in your setup; in the near future pfSense will officially support ESXi.

Answer (score 2):

1. VMware is a company, not a product. What VMware product are you using?
2. Yes, pfSense would work, as well as RRAS, or anything else that has routing capability to route between the two subnets.
3. Create two vSwitches. Connect the relevant VM's to the appropriate vSwitch. Connect your pfSense or RRAS (or whatever) VM to each vSwitch. Configure routing in pfSense or RRAS (or whatever) to route between the two subnets. Configure the relevant VM's to use the pfSense or RRAS (or whatever) VM as their default gateway. Done.

I do this in my home lab with RRAS.

Comment: ESXI 5.5 is what were using sorry

Comment: yea ill peruse pfSense option cheers for the help

Answer (score -1):

The best option i found for this was RRAS role on a 2008R2 Virtual server.

this blog here helps explain the process,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/canberrapfe/archive/2013/04/23/routing-traffic-between-subnets-in-your-hyper-v-lab.aspx

i used Vmware rather than Hyper-V but the same applies, it was a surprisingly painless process and allowed me to replicate a real world network topology and troubleshoot AD replication issues.

Gordon

Comment: "VMWare" is a company, not software. Windows is easily the worst "router" option that fulfills your basic requirements. Good luck.

Comment: Chris you just seem to down vote everything i write cheers, then use your own subjective opinions, perhaps you could expand on why its the "Worst "router" option as it done exactly what i was requiring it to do, i thought providing a little more information would be helpful to anyone reading this. Yes Vmware is a company and i use there products in my environment, its been clearly state further up what software i use. 

thanks

Comment: This "answer" is the only thing I have downvoted, please be careful making assumptions about how other people have voted. You appear to be a native English speaker, but your grammar reflects a person who does not care about the way they are perceived or a pension for accuracy, including distinguishing companies from products. I explicitly stated that Windows will "fulfill your basic requirements", I do not see an issue opining it as the "worst" option. It can not natively simulate potential real-world problems your network may face, including latency, packet-loss, limited bandwidth, etc.